# Setting table_name in ActiveRecord::Base subclass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have an abstract class:

```
class AbstractBrowsable < ActiveRecord::Base  
  self.abstract_class = true
  attr_accessible :heading
  [...]
  def get_following(count)
    AbstractBrowsable.where("heading > ?", self.heading).order('heading ASC').limit(count)
  end
end
```

It has some generic queries like the one above, so in the subclasses I need to set the table name e.g.

```
class Subject < AbstractBrowsable
  AbstractBrowsable.table_name = "subjects"
end
```

The ''only'' way I can get this to work is as shown above, i.e. `AbstractBrowsable.table_name = "subjects"` and not `self.table_name = 'subjects'`. This seems fishy to me, and my Google-Fu only turns up examples using `self.`. Is this OK, or else what am I missing?

If you haven't guessed, I'm new to Ruby/Rails; any help much appreciated. My Rails version is 3.2.13, and Ruby is 1.9.3.

Comment: I think you are trying to do STI: Single Table Inheritance, which is like an abstract object (i.e. Item) as 'parent' of other objects (i.e. Shirt, Car, Glasses, etc.) Am I wrong?

Comment: @MrYoshiji see my comment below cpuguy83's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using self unless you are trying to do STI, which case you'd need to not set abstract_class.

-- edit --

Based on what you described in your comment what you need is to build the functionality into module(s) and include them in your classes.  This is the purpose of modules in Ruby.

Recommend reading this: http://37signals.com/svn/posts/3372-put-chubby-models-on-a-diet-with-concerns

Heres an example:

```
module Browsable
  # Browsable methods
end

class Subject < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Browsable
  # 
end
```

Comment: Thanks for turning me on to STI, but no, that's not what I'm trying to do. Every subclass has and needs its own table (the data isn't coming into the database via Rails, to my hands are tied there). All I want is to store some generic methods common to all of the subclasses but which interact with different tables based on which subclass it is. Maybe this isn't possible?
As I said above, replacing `AbstractBrowsable.table_name = "subjects"` with `self.table_name = "subjects"` in the Subject class does not work.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I ran across that 37signals post last night and had a feeling that was the direction I'd be heading. I'm actually using a combination of mixins and and abstract classes now, and I *think* my code is as DRY as I'm going to get. Cheers.

Comment: Whenever possible try to stay away from class inheritance, unless it makes since...they way I think of it is is this subclass a type of the super class?  If not then it should be done with module inclusion.  I think the way we inherit from ActiveRecord::Base is wrong and only really there for convenience.  Made a gist awhile ago explaining my thoughts on this... some of it is in jest, but still the substance is there. https://gist.github.com/cpuguy83/5452056